# This code view html result None

Tags: python, urllib

I write code view html.But it results None.

```
# coding: UTF-8

import urllib

class View_html:
    def __init__(self):
        url = "http://www.yahoo.com/"
        self.data = urllib.urlopen(url)

    def html(self):
        self.data.read()

if __name__=="__main__":
    a = View_html()
    print a.html()
```

It results

```
None
```

How do I change this code?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `return` keyword:

```
def html(self):
    return self.data.read()
```